# CSV Files in Excel -- Problems with <br> tags

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2007

I am trying to open a CSV file in Excel. The file is a list of product for my online store, and fields include things like "handle", "price", "image url", and so on.

One of the fields, "Body (HTML)" contains the product descriptions. Each of these descriptions contain the HTML tag `<br />` which seems to cause strange behavior in Excel. It appears that the break tags cause all the content below them to be pushed onto a new line, where they appear under the first field.

How can I solve this and keep the content after the break tag in the column it belongs in?

(I'm using Excel 2007 on XP)

Thanks

EDIT: For clarity, the field causing the problem contains raw HTML. Wherever a `<br />` tag appears, Excel seems to inset a line break. But the tag isn't for Excel, it's just part of the product description.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply preg_replage all the `<br />` tags by (for example) 'carriageReturnLine' or any other word that you won't find in your html file.

Then, you just create a little macro in VBA, read each lines in your CSV file and replace 'carriageReturnLine' or whatever with Excel carriage :

```
For i = 0 To UBound(lines_array, 1)
    lines_array(i) = Replace(lines_array(i), "carriageReturnLine", Chr(10))
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't know if this would work as the descriptions are generated inside a WYSIWYG editor inside my eCommerce platform. Or have I misunderstood? -- thanks again

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand something ;)
1) do you want to keep the html as it is (with <br />), or do you want (inside the cell) to have a new line each time there's a <br /> ?
2) in your csv file, do you have line return in html part ? Maybe the problem is that in html part there are some line returns no ?
(sorry for my poor english ... hope you understand).

Comment: if possible, the best would be to have the csv file. At least one row.

Comment: No problem. I have a CSV file that has been exported by my eCommerce platform. One of the fields includes the description for each product - each of these descriptions is written in HTML. Where a <br /> tag appears (as part of the HTML), it seems that Excel breaks and creates a new line. I don't want this new line to be created. I hope that helps! Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah ok i think i get it. :). But now, i need to know : Is the problem in the CSV file, or is it when excel interprets the "<br />". To know that, check your CSV, and tell me if when you have a <br /> it's going to a new line. (better : link to csv file, that would be faster) ;)

Comment: Sorry to make it more complicated, but if i open the file normally in Excel, the layout is okay. However, this causes another problem -- the columns are not formatting as text. So I imported the .csv file as text. It was after doing this that the problem occurred. As far as I can tell, the problem is with excel, not the file. As you suggest, the problem seems to occur in how Excel interprets the <br />. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the columns are not formatting as text" ? If the extension is not CSV i'm not sure excel can read the file like a CSV ...

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the numbers in certain columns were being formatted as "number" rather than "plain text". This caused (for example) the number 00567 to be formatted as 567. When importing the .csv into Excel, there is an option to format the columns as "text". This solved the problem of the leading zeros, but creates the problem that this thread is about (i.e. the problem I asked about first).